# Querying dynamodb returns "Can't Pick _thread.lock"?

Tags: python, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to make a general dynamodb query but keep getting a `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock object`.

```
response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key("Key").eq("Whatever")
        )
```

Any possible pointers? I did some research prior and apparently this error appears when trying to do multithreading, however I am not doing any threading in this script.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
table = boto3.resource("dynamodb", "region").Table('table_name')
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key("Key").eq("Whatever"))
```